# Please help me correct the syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get the an error when  I execute the query below. what I'm doing wrong?

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
select

     so.name 'Table Name'
    ,so.id 'Table ID'
     ,so.xtype
     ,sc.name 'Column Name'
     ,sc.id 'Column ID'
     ,sf.constid
     ,sf.fkeyid 'Object ID of the table with FOREIGN KEY'
     ,sf.rkeyid 'Referenced Table ID'
     ,(select o.name 'Referenced Table' 
    from sysforeignkeys f
     inner join sysobjects o
      on o.id=f.rkeyid
      where o.xtype='U') 

    from sysobjects so
   inner join syscolumns sc 
    on so.id=sc.id
      inner join sysforeignkeys sf
     on so.id=sf.fkeyid 
     where so.xtype='U'
    and (sc.name like 'SSN'
     OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
     OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
      OR sc.name LIKE '%_ssn%'          
    OR sc.name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
    OR sc.name LIKE 'Ssn%');
```

Comment: like ='SSN'  either use LIKE or =, both will cause a prob

Comment: The title can be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your subquery is correct as it has no way of referencing your sysobjects aliased "so". Try this instead. Also I don't think you need such a long where clause.

```
select so.name      [Table Name]
        ,so.id      [Table ID]
        ,so.xtype
        ,sc.name    [Column Name]
        ,sc.id      [Column ID]
        ,sf.constid
        ,sf.fkeyid  [Object ID of the table with FOREIGN KEY]
        ,sf.rkeyid  [Referenced Table ID]
        ,zz.name    [Reference Table]
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc     on so.id = sc.id
inner join sysforeignkeys sf on so.id = sf.fkeyid 

--Use a join here for the reference table column
inner join sysobjects zz     on zz.id = sf.rkeyid

where   so.xtype='U'
        AND(
            sc.name LIKE '%ssn%'
            OR sc.name LIKE '_ocsecno'
            )
```

Comment: I got msg 4104 when I tried your version .   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "zz.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "zz.name" could not be bound.

Comment: Is your SQL Server case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

```
select so.name      [Table Name]
        ,so.id      [Table ID]
        ,so.xtype
        ,sc.name    [Column Name]
        ,sc.id      [Column ID]
        ,sf.constid
        ,sf.fkeyid  [Object ID of the table with FOREIGN KEY]
        ,sf.rkeyid  [Referenced Table ID]
        ,(select TOP 1 o.name 
          from sysforeignkeys f
          inner join sysobjects o on o.id=f.rkeyid
          where o.xtype='U') AS [Referenced Table]
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc     on so.id = sc.id
inner join sysforeignkeys sf on so.id = sf.fkeyid 
where so.xtype='U'
  and (   sc.name like 'SSN'  --<-- Two operator together "LIKE" and  "="
       OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
       OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
       OR sc.name LIKE '%_ssn%'          
       OR sc.name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
       OR sc.name LIKE 'Ssn%');
```

**Important Note**

A sub-query in Select MUST return a scalar value, add `TOP 1` to your sub-query and it should fix the error.

Also use Square Brackets `[]` for column names instead of literal strings.

Comment: good call. corrected but I'm still getting an error   Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @user3561219 have a look I have edited my answer and fixed the problem you are getting now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `where` clause

```
 .....
 where so.xtype='U'
    and (sc.name like 'SSN' -- Here you have a unwanted = or sc.name = 'SSN'
     OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
     OR sc.name LIKE 'ssn%'         
      OR sc.name LIKE '%_ssn%'          
    OR sc.name LIKE '_ocsecno'          
    OR sc.name LIKE 'Ssn%');
```